# Repeat of random number

Tags: python, random

I am trying to capture a random number without it repeating. the larger context is I am trying to get random items out of a list. Is there a way to capture random number [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J91OV.png)when looping without the variable getting repeated, without using pre defined functions? Thank You.

```py
import random

random_var = 0
for i in range(0,10):
    random_var = random.randint(0,10)
```

Answer (score 1):

> the *larger context* is I am trying to get random items out of a list.

You can use `random.sample()` for that:

```py
import random

L = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

for i in random.sample(L, len(L)):
    print(i)
```

Assuming you are ok with it, `random.shuffle()` can be used to modify the list order:

```py
import random

L = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

# L is now in haphazard order
random.shuffle(L)

# prints list in random order
for e in L:
    print(e)
```

---

> I am trying to capture a random number without it repeating.

Try avoid `random.choice()` because you could end up with duplicates:

```py
for i in range(len(L)):
    print(random.choice(L))
```

Sample output:

```
2
1
3
5
5  <-- repeat
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import random

for i in random.sample(range(100), 10):
    print(i)
    ## print(l[i])
```

This will generate 10 number between 0 and 99.